# Multiple Inheritance and Objects C#

Tags: c#, oop

Sorry didn't get any funky title for the question.

I had been taught that .Net(C#) doesn't support **Multiple Inheritance**. But looking at the foo example below I wonder is this really truth ??

```
class fooList
{
    public int Index()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}    
class foo : fooList
{
    public foo()
    { }
}
class testFoo
{
    void test()
    {
        foo obj = new foo();

        // From object
        obj.Equals(obj);
        obj.GetHashCode();
        obj.GetType();
        obj.ToString();

        // From fooList
        obj.Index();
    }
}
```

As we can see that I have a class `fooList` and a class `foo` which inherits `fooList` according to the sayings(C# doesn't support Multiple Inheritance) the object of class `foo` should have only one method which is `Index()` from the `fooList` class, But it has more methods from the object class. It clearly indicates that by default all the classes inherit `object` class. So questions raises

1. Is it really completely true that C# doesn't support Multiple
   Inheritance ?
2. I guess it supports it at CLR level, Than why it doesn't support it
   in coding ?

Comment: This is not a case of multiple inheritence. Every class inherits from object if not otherwise specified. If you inherit from another class directly, you indirectly inherit from object since that class inherits from object. Object is the root to all objects.

Comment: `class fooList` is a shorthand for `class fooList : object`. That should clear your confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C# does not support multiple inheritance of classes at a single level. C# does support multiple *levels* of inheritance in a hierarchy. What you are seeing is that at the top of your inheritance hierachy is `System.Object`, which is the top level base class for classes and structs in .NET.

What you cannot have is:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C : A, B { }
```

What you *can* have:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : B { }
```

Make sense?

For a bit more completeness, C# does allow you to *simulate* multiple inheritance via the usage of interfaces. So let's walk it back.

```
class A { }
interface B { }
class C : A, B { } // legal
```

In this example, the declaration of C *is* legal, and you would need to implement the various members that interface B defines as part of C.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple Inheritance is not what you're seeing here. Multiple Inheritance means that a class derives from two base classes "in parallel", like maybe this:

```
public class Test : Base1, Base2 {}
```

That is not possible.

What you're seeing here (and this works in any object oriented language) is that of course a class A inherits methods and properties from all the entire hierarchy.

For example:

```
public class Test : Base {}
```

inherits all methods from `Base` and `Object`, if `Base` is directly derived from `Object`.

So if you have this hierarchy:

```
public class Base : Object {}
public class A : Base {}
```

`Base` inherits all methods and properties from `Object`, and `A` inherits all methods and properties from `Base` and thus also from `Object`.

Otherwise it would not be possible to build class hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing example of multi label inheritance and not multiple inheritance.

Multiple inheritance means a single class can inherit more than one class.

```
class A: B,C
```

Which is not true in case of c#

Answer (score 1):

You are missunderstanding multiple inheritance. A class can inherit a class which already inherits another class. But a class cannot inherit two or more different classes at the same time.

```
// Default inheritance from Object.
// Class A inherits System.Object
class A     

// Simple inheritance. This is not multiple inheritance.   
// Class B inherits class A, which inherits Object
class B : A     

// Simple inheritance. This is not multiple inheritance.
// Class C inherits class B, which inherits class A, which inherits Object
class C : B  

// Default inheritance from Object.
// Class D inherits System.Object
class D     

// Multiple inheritance
// Class E inherits both class A and class D
class E : A, D

// Multiple inheritance
// Class F inherits both class A and class B
class F : A, B

// Multiple inheritance
// Class G inherits both class C and class D
class G : C, D
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Index() method other methods are from the Object class which is the base class for all the reference type as well as value types. It is very true that C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance but it does support multilevel inheritance, again C# supports multiple inheritance if we are using Interfaces.

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance to remove the ambiguity which can arise if two base classes have a same methods defined in them and it would be confusing by looking at the code that which version of the method would be called. Check out this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/616d520b-ffae-4b3f-9e0c-35c47ce6ccc9).

This uncertainity can be removed by having two interface as shown in the example below;

```
public  interface IA
{
  string SomeMethod();
}

public interface IB
{
  string SomeMethod();
}

class MyConcreteClass:IA, IB
{
  string IA.SomeMethod()
  {
     return "For IA";       
  }

  string IB.SomeMethod()
  {
     return "For IB";       
  }
}

IA concA = new MyConcreteClass();
IB concB = new MyConcreteClass();

 Console.WriteLine(concA.SomeMethod()); // print "For IA"
 Console.WriteLine(concB.SomeMethod()); // print "For IB"
```

As you can see we can have different behaviors for the functions of both the interface by explicitly defining them in the derived class which would prevent from any ambiguity.

One more point to note here is that the function definitions in the derived class cannot be public as it cant be accessed by the instance of the derived type.